# How can TCP be used in order to implement DHCP and under which circumstances is this preferable?

Tags: tcp, dhcp, udp

I am pretty new to the computer networking studies and was learning about the DHCP protocol. It is implemented based on UDP, as I've gathered, but is there a way for it to be implemented over TCP? What would lead to this implementation? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds like homework... Doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: You cannot broadcast or multicast with TCP because it creates connections between two specific endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be a very practical implementation, you could e.g. use link-local addresses to establish a TCP connection to a "DHCP over TCP" server and use that to lease a non-local address.

Discovery would still require broadcast or multicast, disqualifying TCP. Alternatively, the DHCP server could use a well-known, static link-local address that doesn't need discovery.

Answer (score 4):

Given that DHCP relies on connection-less data transfer and broadcast and TCP is connection-oriented and does not support broadcasts one cannot implement the underlying design of DHCP with TCP.